# Sharepoint Intranet Samples

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am in the process of building sharepoint intranet portal for a online retail company. Can any one of you point me in a right direction to see some sample intranet site or images. I would like to see a well developed sharepoint sites.

Answer (score 0):

For Sharepoint intranet designs, please see this site.

[This is the site you are looking for](http://www.topsharepoint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[SPSDemo](http://www.spsdemo.com) (formerly WSSDemo) has links to a number of SharePoint demo sites. Mostly internet-facing, I believe.

http://www.spsdemo.com/websites/Lists/OldList/AllItems.aspx